# Maintaining hyperlinks after adding data, or sorting a list

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula, match, worksheet-function

I have a list of a few hundred titles, with a few columns per entry (i.e. name, date, and such). Among the names I added entries that just say "A", "B", "C", etc., since it makes it easier when scrolling through the document, looking for specific names, to know where - for example - "H" starts.

As the list grew, I added hyperlinks to the top of the document to be able to jump to the A/B/C/etc.-entries. However, when adding new data and sorting it in, or when sorting the list by date or anything else, the hyperlink "Go to: A" (as an example) keeps linking to the original cell - A1 - despite the data of that cell (the actual text "A") is now in A42.

Is there anyway to maintain the hyperlinks, through sorting and [mainly] adding new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula in A1 is `=HYPERLINK($I1,"Go to: "&H1)` to be copied down as appropriate.

[image: SO17535313 example revised]

(=MATCH ‘does not like’ the hyperlinked cells in the same range as is searched for the letters.)

Alternatively in Row1 (but still in a new ColumnA) and copied down, without the need for ColumnH:I :

```
=HYPERLINK("[SO17535313.xlsx]Sheet1!"&"B"&MATCH(CHAR(64+ROW()),B:B,0),"Go to: "&CHAR(64+ROW()))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems to work great through adding new data. But I run in to a weird problem. It works fine for "C" and down, but "A" and "B" get a "Circular Reference Warning". Any idea what's causing this? Happens both when I manually input the code, and when I extend the series.

Comment: After adding the rest of the alphabet, "B" (the "Go to: B" hyperlink, that is) solved itself. "A" is still broken, with the status bar saying "Circular Reference: H1". (My list is in A30:A106, btw, and I changed to code to reflect the name of the document and sheet I'm using.)

Comment: The new code (formula?) worked perfectly. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

- Save the Excel spreadsheet a "Web Page" (and NOT "Single File Web Page".)
- Open the "Web Page" version in Excel.
- Sort it.
- Save it as an Excel spreadsheet.

Each link will be preserved in the appropriate cell.

Answer (score 1):

There is an acknowledged bug in Excel related to hyperlinks and sorting.

[KB214328:  Hyperlinks are removed or invalid after you sort cells that contain these hyperlinks in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214328)

I should note that in my case I'm making hyperlinks to documents outside of Excel (ProjecWise).

My work around is to store all the hyperlinks as text in one column and use the Excel Hyperlink() function to generate the hyperlink for each row in another column.  When you want to paste a hyperlink from an external source (like a browser), select the cell and then paste the link into the function box below the ribbon, instead of pasting directly into the cell.  This will give you the text and not create a hyperlink object in the cell.

I don't understand the problem completely, but from my new understanding the way Excel handles hyperlinks, hyperlinks in cells are somehow linked to a collection of hyperlinks on the sheet object.  When you sort the rows on the sheet, the sheet hyperlink references begin to return bad references.  I couldn't find a unique 'handle' to the sheet hyperlink references, but noticed that the h.Parent.Top was changing as I sorted.

```
Public Sub ShowSheetHyperlinks()
' Use this to demonstrate the issue acknowledged here:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214328
' Add some hyperlinks in a column of a spreadsheet and random values in a column next to it.
' Run this routine.  Then sort the values by the first or second column and run this routine again.
' You may have to do this a few times, and/or copy and paste your hyperlink cells to other cells.
' Eventually you will see that the results change after the two columns are sorted.
' (You may not need two columns, but it may help to randomize the sorting.)

    Dim h As Hyperlink

    Debug.Print "Hyperlinks on " & ActiveSheet.Name & ": " & ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Count

    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        ' After you sort the list of hyperlinks, you will notice the values in the
        ' three columns below.  I am truncating the address to just see the last 20 characters.
        Debug.Print h.TextToDisplay, h.Parent.Top, Right(h.Address, 20)
    Next

End Sub
```